# Why the reinterpret_cast operator is considered dangerous in cpp? is there a better approach?

Tags: c++, file, file-handling, reinterpret-cast

I was studying Random access in files in cpp. I came across reinterpret_cast operator. It allows you to cast a pointer from one type to another type, even if those types are not related in any way. However, it is stated that it is considered dangerous and may produce unexpected results and program crashes. I wanted to understand why and how.

The code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream file("example.txt", ios::out);
    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    file.seekp(4 * sizeof(int), ios::beg);
    int newValue = 50;
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&newValue), sizeof(int));
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted. `reinterpret_cast` may produce problems, but not always. Specifically I believe a cast from any data pointer to `char*` is allowed.

Comment: Actually there is one thing wrong with your code. Because you are performing binary I/O you should open the file in binary mode `fstream file("example.txt", ios::out|ios::binary);`. Failing to do that could result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: One thing to be aware of here is that the size and endianness of `int` are not necessarily the same for all architectures/compilers, so you may run into problems when transferring the data between machines... This shouldn't be an issue, if the programs reading and writing the data are compiled with the same compiler, you shouldn't get into trouble though...

Comment: "Dangerous" doesn't mean that it *always* causes problems. Just that it is *easy* to use it wrong. Like `reinterpret_cast<Cat>(Rocket)` might not work well.

Comment: Minor point: you don't need to call `file.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: This is fine, and necessary, because there is no version of `write` which is overloaded to take something like `int*`. If such a thing existed, you could use it instead of having to use a pointer cast. The reason for using `reinterpreted_cast` is because you are not casting within an inheritance hierarchy, which is what `dynamic_cast` is for.

Comment: This seems relevant here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data type of a pointer defines the meaning of the bits it is pointing to. For example, unsigned integers just use binary encoding, i.e, a unsigned 4-bit int 1010 would be interpreted as a decimal 10. However, if you were to change the pointer type to signed, the bits are read in [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and interpreted as a decimal -6. Floating point types again have a totally different bit representation (i.e. [the IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). In other words: **The pointer type defines how the bits are interpreted**.

`reinterpret_cast` only changes the pointer type, but not the stored bits. This means, that any semantics given by the previous data type are lost after conversion, and the interpreted values before and after the cast may vastly differ from each other. You should only use this cast when you are aware of the bit representation of your data and need to manipulate it.

This may cause trouble not only concerning the semantics, but also the memory, as it allows you to cast to wider data types.

```
uint32_t A[1] = {1};
uint64_t* B = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(A);
```

This is a typical example of abusing memory with reinterpret_cast. You can easily get a pointer to the same memory address that `A` points to, but `B` expects 64 instead of 32 bits per element. Hence, dereferencing `B` has the same effect as reading from `A[1]`: You are trying to access memory, that was not part of the original data.

Comment: `uint64_t* B = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(A);` causes undefined behavior when accessing through `B` regardless of the array size issue. It is an aliasing violation and possibly a misaligned access. _That's_ actually why `reinterpret_cast` is so dangerous: Even if it seems to make sense, it likely causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have `unsigned int` B and `signed float` A. They have the same size and you might think that `uint32_t* B = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(A)` will give some meaningful result. But `signed float` has totally different bit pattern that includes sign bit, exponent part and fraction part. Now you can imagine how irrelevant the result of such cast will be where sign, exponent and fraction treated as one positive integer all together. `reinterpret_cast` is one of the best sources of undefined behavior if not used properly.

Comment: `uint32_t* B = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(A)` causes undefined behavior when accessing `B` regardless of how the bit representations correspond. It is an aliasing violation and possibly a misaligned access. _That's_ actually why `reinterpret_cast` is so dangerous: Even if it seems to make sense, it likely causes undefined behavior.